# How to join results of 2 tables based on not condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, say `TableA` & `TableB` defined like this:

> create table TableA(id int, name varchar(20), partNumber varchar(30));

with values as:

```
insert into TableA values(1,'a1','10');
insert into TableA values(2,'a2','20');
insert into TableA values(3,'a3','30');
insert into TableA values(4,'a4','40');
```

> create table TableB(id int, name varchar(20), partNumber
>   varchar(30));

```
insert into TableB values(5,'b1','10');
insert into TableB values(6,'b2','20');
insert into TableB values(7,'b3','60');
insert into TableB values(8,'b4','70');
```

Now in the result I want to join both the tables and get all the records from `TableB` and only those records from `TableA` where the `TableA's partNumber` column value that is not matching with any value of `TableB's partNumber`.

I have tried below queries and all of them gave same result of 14 records which is not correct.

**Query 1 :**

> select b.id as Bid, b.name as Bname, b.partNumber as BPart, a.id as
>   Aid, a.name as Aname, a.partNumber as APart from TableB b left join
>   TableA a on a.partNumber!=b.partNumber;

**Query 2 :**

> select b.id as Bid, b.name as Bname, b.partNumber as BPart, a.id as
>   Aid, a.name as Aname, a.partNumber as APart from TableB b , TableA a
>   where a.partNumber!=b.partNumber;

**Query 3 :**

> select b.id as Bid, b.name as Bname, b.partNumber as BPart, a.id as
>   Aid, a.name as Aname, a.partNumber as APart from TableB b left join
>   TableA a on a.partNumber not in (select a.id as Aid from TableB b join
>   TableA a on a.partNumber=b.partNumber);

Can someone please help me where I am making mistake here? what is the correct way to get the results.

I am expecting the output to be like this:

```
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
| Bid  | Bname | BPart | Aid  | Aname | APart |
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
|    5 | b1    | 10    |    3 | a3    | 30    |
|    5 | b1    | 10    |    4 | a4    | 40    |
|    6 | b2    | 20    |    3 | a3    | 30    |
|    6 | b2    | 20    |    4 | a4    | 40    |
|    7 | b3    | 60    |    3 | a3    | 30    |
|    7 | b3    | 60    |    4 | a4    | 40    |
|    8 | b4    | 70    |    3 | a3    | 30    |
|    8 | b4    | 70    |    4 | a4    | 40    |
+------+-------+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

So here what I mean is in the result I don't want the records of `TableA` where `partNumber` is `10, 20` because the values are present in `TableB's partNumber`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, name, partNumber, Aid, Aname, Apart
FROM TableB AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id AS Aid, name AS Aname, partNumber AS Apart
            FROM TableA AS a
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM TableB AS b
                              WHERE b.partNumber = a.partNumber)) AS c
ORDER BY id
```

The idea is to select all required records from `TableA` using a `NOT EXISTS` clause. Then `CROSS JOIN` the derived table from this query with `Table1` to get all possible combinations.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8123/2)

Comment: Perfect, it worked. If you don't mind can you please suggest some source (online links or books or documentation) where I can learn better SQL. I have knowledge of basic SQL and can write some join queries, but when it comes to writing queries of this kind then I really feel bad.

Comment: @user3181365 Glad I was able to help. The best source is SO! Getting involved in real-life problems' solving cannot be compared to any online source or Book. As far as RDBMS design is concerned, [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Server-Relational-Database-Design-Implementation/dp/143020866X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1433424613&sr=8-1&keywords=sql+server+design) book was a real life saver.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding, I always use and work on Oracle database, so does this book help me to learn better queries as it says SQL Server?

Comment: @user3181365 Well, professionally I have worked almost exclusively in SQL Server so far. Unfortunately this book is SQL Server oriented.

Comment: Thank you once again for solving my issue and giving advice, I really appreciate :)