# How to join 2 entities based on NOT condition

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hql

I have 2 tables - TableA and TableB for example with some data in them as defined in this post - [How to join results of 2 tables based on not condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644726/how-to-join-results-of-2-tables-based-on-not-condition)

Now I am planning to create Hibernate entities for both the tables and the entities are not related to each other.

Now I want to get the results based on NOT condition as given in my earlier post which I have mentioned.

The result is to use the SQL query:

```
SELECT id, name, partNumber, Aid, Aname, Apart
FROM TableB AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id AS Aid, name AS Aname, partNumber AS Apart
            FROM TableA AS a
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM TableB AS b
                              WHERE b.partNumber = a.partNumber)) AS c
ORDER BY id
```

Now how to create **HQL query or criteria queries** for such scenario's. I have gone through the Hibernate documentation for HQL & Criteria queries but I was not able to understand how can I convert this SQL query to HQL and Criteria queries. Can you please help me on this.

**Update 1:**

Based on the answer given by Vlad I am not getting correct output.

Here is the Code I have written:

```
List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery(
                "select a, b " + "from TableB b, TableA a "
                        + "where b.partNumber != a.partNumber "
                        + "ORDER BY b.id").list();

        for (Object[] objects : list) {
            for (Object object : objects) {
                System.out.println(object);
            }
        }
```

I got below output:

```
A: id=2, name=a2, partNumber=20
B: id=5, name=b1, partNumber=10

A: id=3, name=a3, partNumber=30
B: id=5, name=b1, partNumber=10

A: id=4, name=a4, partNumber=40
B: id=5, name=b1, partNumber=10

A: id=1, name=a1, partNumber=10
B: id=6, name=b2, partNumber=20

A: id=3, name=a3, partNumber=30
B: id=6, name=b2, partNumber=20

A: id=4, name=a4, partNumber=40
B: id=6, name=b2, partNumber=20

A: id=1, name=a1, partNumber=10
B: id=7, name=b3, partNumber=60

A: id=2, name=a2, partNumber=20
B: id=7, name=b3, partNumber=60

A: id=3, name=a3, partNumber=30
B: id=7, name=b3, partNumber=60

A: id=4, name=a4, partNumber=40
B: id=7, name=b3, partNumber=60

A: id=1, name=a1, partNumber=10
B: id=8, name=b4, partNumber=70

A: id=2, name=a2, partNumber=20
B: id=8, name=b4, partNumber=70

A: id=3, name=a3, partNumber=30
B: id=8, name=b4, partNumber=70

A: id=4, name=a4, partNumber=40
B: id=8, name=b4, partNumber=70
```

From output I got records of `TableA` with id's = `1,2,3,4` & for `TableB`id's= `5,6,7,8`.

But the desired output should have id's of `TableA` as `3&4` and for `TableB` id's as `5,6,7,8`. The details are given in my other post : [How to join results of 2 tables based on not condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644726/how-to-join-results-of-2-tables-based-on-not-condition)

**Query generated by Hibernate is:**

```
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        a,
        b 
    from
        TableB b,
        TableA a 
    where
        b.partNumber != a.partNumber 
    ORDER BY
        b.id */ 

select
    tablea1_.id as id1_0_0_,
    tableb0_.id as id1_1_1_,
    tablea1_.name as name2_0_0_,
    tablea1_.partNumber as partNumber3_0_0_,
    tableb0_.name as name2_1_1_,
    tableb0_.partNumber as partNumber3_1_1_ 
from
    TableB tableb0_ cross 
join
    TableA tablea1_ 
where
    tableb0_.partNumber<>tablea1_.partNumber 
order by
    tableb0_.id
```

**Update 2:**

Code that I have tried now:

```
List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery("select b, a "
                + "from TableB b, TableA a "
                + "where not exists ( "
                + "select 1 "
                + "from TableB b1, TableA a1 "
                + "where "
                + "b1.partNumber = a1.partNumber and "
                + "b1.id = b.id and "
                + "a1.id = a.id " 
                + ") "
                + "order by b.id").list();
        for (Object[] objects : list) {
            for (Object object : objects) {
                System.out.println(object);
            }
        }
```

Query generated by Hibernate:

```
Hibernate: 

select
            tableb0_.id as id1_1_0_,
            tablea1_.id as id1_0_1_,
            tableb0_.name as name2_1_0_,
            tableb0_.partNumber as partNumb3_1_0_,
            tablea1_.name as name2_0_1_,
            tablea1_.partNumber as partNumb3_0_1_ 
        from
            TableB tableb0_ cross 
        join
            TableA tablea1_ 
        where
            not (exists (select
                1 
            from
                TableB tableb2_ cross 
            join
                TableA tablea3_ 
            where
                tableb2_.partNumber=tablea3_.partNumber 
                and tableb2_.id=tableb0_.id 
                and tablea3_.id=tablea1_.id)) 
        order by
            tableb0_.id
```

Output of this query:

```
B: id=5, name=b1, partNumber=10
A: id=4, name=a4, partNumber=40
B: id=5, name=b1, partNumber=10
A: id=2, name=a2, partNumber=20
B: id=5, name=b1, partNumber=10
A: id=3, name=a3, partNumber=30
B: id=6, name=b2, partNumber=20
A: id=1, name=a1, partNumber=10
B: id=6, name=b2, partNumber=20
A: id=4, name=a4, partNumber=40
B: id=6, name=b2, partNumber=20
A: id=3, name=a3, partNumber=30
B: id=7, name=b3, partNumber=60
A: id=3, name=a3, partNumber=30
B: id=7, name=b3, partNumber=60
A: id=1, name=a1, partNumber=10
B: id=7, name=b3, partNumber=60
A: id=4, name=a4, partNumber=40
B: id=7, name=b3, partNumber=60
A: id=2, name=a2, partNumber=20
B: id=8, name=b4, partNumber=70
A: id=3, name=a3, partNumber=30
B: id=8, name=b4, partNumber=70
A: id=1, name=a1, partNumber=10
B: id=8, name=b4, partNumber=70
A: id=4, name=a4, partNumber=40
B: id=8, name=b4, partNumber=70
A: id=2, name=a2, partNumber=20
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a theta-style join:

```
select b, a
from TableB b, TableA a 
where not exists (
    select 1
    from TableB b1, TableA a1
    where 
        b1.partNumber = a1.partNumber and
        b1.id = b.id and
        a1.id = a.id    
)   
order by b.id
```

or you can use an SQL query to fetch entities as well:

```
List result = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT b.*, c.* \n" +
        "FROM TableB b AS t\n" +
        "CROSS JOIN (SELECT id AS Aid, name AS Aname, partNumber AS Apart\n" +
        "            FROM TableA AS a\n" +
        "            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1\n" +
        "                              FROM TableB AS b\n" +
        "                              WHERE b.partNumber = a.partNumber)) AS c\n" +
        "ORDER BY b.id ")
        .addEntity("b", B.class)
        .addEntity("a", A.class)
        .list();
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for answering, but the solution is not working as expected. I have added more details on what I have tried and what output I got, please check.

Comment: This query is also not giving expected output. I have given details in my `Update 2` session.

Comment: Try adding a distinct.

Comment: Hi Vlad, added distinct in the query but the result is same as the one shown in my Update 2 section. Please let me know if you want to look at the logs so I will update with details in my question.

Comment: Then a native query is your only option. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time to answer my queries. So does it mean hibernate HQL or Criteria's will not support all types of queries? If possible can you please point me to some link or document where I can see what are the drawbacks of hibernate. I am just asking to improve my knowledge on hibernate, just curiosity.

Comment: HQL doesn't support joining a table expression. You could emulate the native query result with 2 queries. The first one selects all rows from B which have no equivalent in A. The other one selects all from A with no equivalent on B. As for docs, you could Google Hibernate vs SQL.

Comment: Thank you, What it means when you say `joining a table expression`? I am also planning to do some research based on your answer to see if I can get the required HQL, so I will accept it in few hours.

Comment: The "Cross join (select ..) as c" is what I was referring to.

Comment: I am looking for an option on how to solve this using HQL or criteria queries as mentioned in my post instead of using native SQL queries.

Comment: Hi Vlad, the HQL was not working and returning wrong data, so when I told you then have suggested me to use native SQL query.

Comment: I don't want to advertise my framework here but I just wanted to let you know, that I am integrated support for CTEs in https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence which is more or less what you want. Internally it uses a very nice mechanism of hibernate used for views. You can put your `table expression` into a @Subquery annotation defined on a new (virtual) entity class. Cross join that new entity and you should semantically get what you initially wrote.

Comment: It's actually `@Subselect`