# What are Relational Objects?

Tags: database, jpa, persistence

I am referring to this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_architecture.htm for learning JPA ,Here a table is given [image]

In query row what is relational object they are referring to?
Are they the objects of entity classes which I am making or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`Query`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) indeed returns instances of entities, but it can also simply return arrays (i.e. rows), or lists of objects that are not entities.

Comment: Now with lists of objects we mean that we write a query, they just return some tuples which doesn't have the structure of the given entity classes. So can we store it in the object of classes which are not entity class.I don't know if I am clear or not.

Comment: `select p.name, p.birthDate from Person p` will return arrays containing a String and a Date, for example. String and Date are not entities. `select new PersonInfo(p.name, p.birthDate) from Person p` will return instances of PersonInfo, which is not en entity.

Comment: PersonInfo is just a class containing two variables having datatype string and date . Okay thanks.

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing in the same link JPA relationship is given ,can you point to any link where more description is given about it.

Comment: The specifications are readable, and so is the Hibernate reference documentation. But you'll learn more by practicing and solving concrete problems.

Comment: @JBNizet, Hi JB, can you please take a look at my post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894928/how-to-join-2-entities-based-on-not-condition